# Nested Routes in REACT ROUTER DOM, wrapping Components in Router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have 2 components, I want One component common in some of  the routes and other component common in remaining routes.

In the both component I am using {props.children} in both component for the nested routes.

MY code is :

```
<Router history={history}>
  <div className='routeContainer'>
    <Switch>

      <Component1>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path='/abc' component={ComponentAbc} />
      </Component1>

      <Component2>
        <Route exact path='/def' component={ComponentDEF} />
        <Route exact path='/xyz' component={ComponentXYZ} />
      </Component2>
    </Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

In Component1 and Component 2 i am using {this.props.children}
its as below :

```
render () {
 return (
  <div>

      <SideBar />
      <Header />
      {this.props.children} 
  </div>
 )
}
```

This is not working, Please Help to make this structure working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "All children of a  `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
>   Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered."  - [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md)

If you want a parent of the route components, you can do one of the following:

1. Wrap inside Components
2. Wrap inside *RouteProps - component*

Either way you need to remove everything but `<Routes/>` or `<Redirects/>` inside `<Switch>`

*Example for alternative **2**:*

```
<Route exact path='/' component={()=> (
  <Component1>
    <Dashboard />
  </Component1>  
)} />
```